# Using Connection Pool in MVC with EF Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to know how to use the connection pool available in IIS 7 and configure the EF to fecth DB conenctions from Connection Pool

And another i am facing is when ever i use where or `FirstorDefault()` or `Savechanges()` new db connections get opened

How can i avoid that and use the opened connection for all the transactions?

Comment: ConnectionPool get connections from your `Web.config` file. If your application doesn't have connetions in there it gets connections from default IIS `Web.config`.

Comment: by default, connection pooling is available and used (once open connections will be used for following contexts), these connections will be closed once the context doesnt need them anymore and opened again later. if you want to keep an connection open all the time, you should declare it top-level and use it in the DbContext(Connection,false) constructor.

Comment: @ teo Van Kot THanks i have given the Connection string in Context File if i remove that and configure the Connection String in  IIS will the Web application use Coonection Pool